# How would you rewrite this struct pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

How would you rewrite the following statement using the structure pointer operator, `->`:

```
*(*strPtr).num = 10
```

I'm confused as to what this even stands for. Is this some kind of double pointer?

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't understand the pointer part

Comment: `x->y` means `(*x).y` and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

The structure probably looks something like

```
struct str { int* num; };
```

with `strPtr` declared like

```
str* strPtr;
```

Your code stores `10` in the location pointed to by `num` in the `str` pointed to by `strPtr`.

It can be rewritten as

```
*strPtr->num = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
*strPtr->num = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a corresponding statement could look like

```
*strPtr->num = 10;
```

where data member `num` has type `int *`

For example

```
struct aStruct { int *num; } str;

str.num = new int;

aStruct *strPtr = &str;

*strPtr->num = 10;
```

or

```
*( *strPtr).num  = 10;
```

Take into account that postfix operators `->` and `.` have higher priority than unary operator `*`